# If you restart your phone or router they looking for a new IP?

Tags: networking, android, dhcp

If you restart your phone or router,they automatically send a discover request to
the dhcp server to get new ip?
I'm a little confused,because when i removes from the outlet the router for 5 minutes,i do not get a new ip,but when the phone is off even for 2 minutes I get a new ip address.
(I'm talking about a phone that is **not** connected to a router, the internet comes from the cellular operator)

Comment: It depends entirely on how the ISP decided to set up it's network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there a way to force an Android phone and router to request a new address?

Comment: Based on your question you seem to talk about a public IP, because a phone and a router can have "multiple IP" if the providers uses CGNAT: the one IP is assigned to the device and the other is visible to servers on the internet (public IP).

Comment: No. They send a request for _an_ IP address. Depending on the auto-configuration technology they could even be explicitly requesting the previous IP. // Either way, it's the ISP deciding the IP assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm a little confused,because when i removes from the outlet the router for 5 minutes,i do not get a new ip,but when the phone is off even for 2 minutes I get a new ip address. (I'm talking about a phone that is not connected to a router, the internet comes from the cellular operator)

Although cellular networks don't use DHCP as such, it doesn't really matter whether they do, the answer is still the same "it depends on a lot of things". So let's just pretend the question is about DHCP (like you'd find on a LAN).

First, it depends on the DHCP client. It **can** either go straight to re-requesting the address it remembers from previously (e.g. stored on disk), but it **also can** just do the whole discover process from zero every time (e.g. expecting the server to reissue the same lease, or just not caring about it).

If the device has storage it'll probably remember the last lease it had and will try to refresh it – but it doesn't actually have to. If it's a computer, it might remember leases individually for each Wi-Fi network, or it might not (and keep trying to reclaim lease A on network B...)

Second, it depends on the DHCP server. For "reboot" requests (i.e. "please give me the same address I had earlier"), it should honor the request *if* the lease hasn't expired yet. But some DHCP servers let you claim the desired address even if the lease *has* expired, as long as the address itself is still "free". On the other hand, some DHCP servers *don't* honor such requests at all and will insist on always giving you a random address.

It's similar for fresh lease requests, too – sometimes the DHCP server will realize that you already have a valid lease, and will just give you the same address again, but sometimes you get a new address while the old lease gets overwritten. Again, depends on the DHCP server software and configuration.

Also, normally DHCP servers identify you by the "Client ID" (which is usually just the MAC address, though not always). But with WAN connections, if the ISP wants, they could identify you by *physical line* – the so-called "Option 82" could be injected by hardware somewhere along the way, to indicate e.g. which physical Ethernet port you're using. This method is sometimes used by ISPs to give you the same IP address even if the whole router has been changed.

Other IP address configuration methods (e.g. IPCP that's used in PPPoE, and whatever is used in 3G/4G) might work differently, e.g. they might not have the feature for the client to request a specific address, but the overall point stays: there's no fixed rule, it depends.

Comment: thank you for the answer,you may know a source of information that centralizes lease times for isp's In the world?

Comment: I'd be somewhat surprised if there was one.

Comment: And statistically how long does the lease last?  I realized that even if I wait the x time this is not sure I will get a new ip address
But let's assume IP addresses are caught quickly(then even if the router asks for the same address it can not get it)

Comment: In other words, I'm trying to statistically figure out how long it will take for a router that is not plugged in (and therefore can not renew a lease) to get a new address, assuming unused addresses are taken in time 0

Comment: @NFLX, leases last as long as the network operator decides they should.  I've seen times as high as a week, and as low as an hour.

Answer (score 1):

The way it works to the best of my knowledge is as such: Your router's dhcp lease expires and it requests a new one from one of the dhcp servers configured, either a set address or it gets it from you isp. Most commercial plans (some corporate plans pay extra for a static one) are for a dynamic forward facing ip address, which means it can change whenever the isp pleases after your router has been rebooted or the lease has expired, but often it doesnt change very often at all just because it is harder nowadays with an increasingly limited ipv4 address pool that isps have to work with (if you are indeed using ipv4) so the isp gives you the same address after every request unless it needs to give you a new one for some reason. Cellular networks work a little different, and it makes sense that they change everybody's addresses more often since there are so many clients going on and offline all the time, but I don't know all that much about them so I can't give a difinitive answer as to why it gives you a new ip everytime you shut down your phone. Hope you understand now!

Also I looked at this answer on computing.net: https://www.computing.net/answers/networking/why-doesnt-my-dynamic-ip-address-ever-change/40000.html

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to force a new IP:

1. Turn off the router for a time that exceeds the ISP's allocated time
   for keeping your IP,
2. Use a VPN to give yourself a new IP (usually VPN servers do not keep
   or remember the old IP).

Comment: Thanks, just to be sure I understood correctly,the isp dhcp server "says" to the computer, this is your IP address,I will decide when the address becomes expired,and if you do not request to reuse the address after the time I have set,the address is released to the address pool,and it does not matter if you turn off and on the router, the address is still yours (if it has not expired yet)

Comment: It's simpler like: You were gone for too long and I have taken away your reserved IP, but don't worry - you get a shiny new one.

Comment: and how the dhcp server can say that there was no connection for a long time,It is necessary to keep the connection alive,or the ip address gets an expiration date?

Comment: I don't think the DHCP lease is significant here, as its normal duration is 24 hours. The ISP's reservation time is usually measured in minutes.